# Adding an object datasource to an SSRS report in an MVC Project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reporting-services

I have added an SSRS report to my MVC project, but when I go to add a dataset all I have in the data source wizard is SQL data connections.  I had worked with SSRS reports in the past and I was able to use business objects.  But that was a WPF project.

Is there something I am missing to let this be available for MVC Projects?  Below is an image and the data sources is empty.  Clicking new only bring us a new SQL connection.

[image]

In my WPF Project I have the following:

[image]

I just created a new DLL project and added a report and I get the following:

[image]

How can I get this in an ASP MVC Project?

Comment: show us screenshot, it's not clear what the problem is

Comment: Where do you locate your .rdlc? As far as i know you should close .rdlc buld project and then open again to see anything in this dropdown

Comment: @teovankot I added the RDLC into the web project.  Just a folder called Reports.  Should this instead be moved to a different kind of project?

Comment: No, have you tried close rdlc, buid and then open?

Comment: @teovankot No luck, though looking a bit deeper it looks like this is an issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15146425/creating-reports-in-asp-net-with-entity-framework  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11038288/issues-setting-rdlc-datasource-to-object  

It looks like I may need to add it it another project and then copy it back.